# [JS/HTML/PHP]Specific div after resfresh page

Tags: javascript, html

I have website with 5 divs and nav with 5 options. I manipulate those elements in JS like that:

```
var homeMain = document.getElementById('div_1');
var productMain = document.getElementById('div_2');
var contactMain = document.getElementById('div_3');
var helpMain = document.getElementById('div_4');
var loginMain = document.getElementById('div_5');

homeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toogle(homeMain);
});
productButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toogle(productMain);
});
contactButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toogle(contactMain);
});
helpButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toogle(helpMain);
});
loginButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toogle(loginMain);
});
registerButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toogle(loginMain);
});

function toogle(element) {
    this.homeMain.style.display = "none";
    this.productMain.style.display = "none";
    this.contactMain.style.display = "none";
    this.helpMain.style.display = "none";
    this.loginMain.style.display = "none";
    element.style.display = "block"
}
```

And I have problem with login page. When I put bad login or password website refresh.
So it's main page. I want back to login page.
I don't want use jquery.

Comment: what kind of code did you make trying to redirect back to the login?

Comment: my form redirect to same page- index.php which check if post data is set and valid data with db.

Comment: in the return from the php saying the login is incorrect you can set a url like `index.php?login-failed`, and check if login-failed exists and reapply block styling tot the loginMain when its there, or call an echo with <script> inside but that is a little bit dirty

Comment: Ok, work :)  but I don't know if it's good way for style`<?php
if (isset($_GET['bad'])) {
    echo '<div class="login" id="div_5" style="display: block;">';
} else{
    echo '<div class="login" id="div_5" style="display: none;">';
}
?>`